# jw player skins xml and swf

Tags: xml, zend-framework, jwplayer, skin

i have jw player on in project and it work fine. and when i download some of skins they work fine.

Problem is some of the skins is not working, and the folder on netbeans show me that is is unrecognized even though i download it from the official website.

Does anyone know how i can put a XML skin .

Answer (score 1):

i found out how just put the .swf in the mediaplayer folder and then i used this code in the helper. and the same thing for XML files.

```
public function Mediaplayer($VideoPath, $width, $height) {
    return '<object id="player" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" name="player" width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '">
    <param name="movie" value="/mediaplayer/player.swf" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="file=' . $VideoPath . '&image=' . str_replace('.flv', '.jpg', str_replace('/flv/', '/thumb/', $VideoPath)) . '&skin='.URL_ADDRESS.'/mediaplayer/comet.swf"'.logo.file ( 'test' ).' />
    <embed
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        id="player2"
        name="player2"
        src="/mediaplayer/player.swf"
        width="' . $width . '"
        height="' . $height . '"
        allowscriptaccess="always"
        allowfullscreen="true"
        flashvars="file=' . $VideoPath . '&image=' . str_replace('.flv', '.jpg', str_replace('/flv/', '/thumb/', $VideoPath)) . '&skin='.URL_ADDRESS.'/mediaplayer/comet.swf"
    />  </object>';
}
```